# why when I declare an int variable my aplication freezes? C program

Tags: c, server, client, fork, serversocket

this is my code for the server so far:
a function that finds if a word is in a file:

```
int Search_in_File_name(char *fname, char *str) {
    FILE *fp;
    int line_num = 1;
    int find_result = 0;
    char temp[512];
    if((fp = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) {
        return(-1);
    }


    while(fgets(temp, 512, fp) != NULL) {
        if((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL) {
            //printf("\n[copil] logare reusita");
            find_result++;
        }
        line_num++;
    }

    if(find_result == 0) {
        //printf("\nnume incorect");
        fclose(fp);
        return(3);
    }
    
    //Close the file if still open.
    if(fp) {
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return(4);
}
```

and main where i have to look see if a client logs in before doing something else. I used fork for every client that connects to the server. I want to create a file in my project directory for every client and i need the number of the client to do that( or the port specified by "ntohs(newAddr.sin_port)" but i can't obtain the number of the client because i can't declare any int variables.

```
int main(){

    int sockfd, ret;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

    int newSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in newAddr;

    socklen_t addr_size;

    char buffer[1024];
    pid_t childpid;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0){
        printf("[-]Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+]Server Socket is created.\n");

    memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    ret = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));  //asociaza adresa serverAddr(localhost) la socketul creat (sockfd)
    if(ret < 0){
        printf("[-]Error in binding.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+]Bind to port %d\n", PORT);

    if(listen(sockfd, 10) == 0){ //marcheaza socketul (sockfd) ca fiind socketul care va accepta o conexiune viitoare si limita maxima de conexiuni in asteptare 
        printf("[+]Listening....\n");
    }else{
        printf("[-]Error in binding.\n");
    }

    while(1){
        newSocket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&newAddr, &addr_size); //ia prima conexiune din lista asociata lui sockfd prin listen si creaza un nou socket si returneaza un descriptor de fisier pentru acel nou socket
        if(newSocket < 0){
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Connection accepted from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
        
        int i=0; 
        if((childpid = fork()) == 0){
            close(sockfd);
            int ok=0;
            char* nume_fisier;
            
            while(1){
                
                recv(newSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);
                if(strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0){
                    printf("Disconnected from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
                    break;

                }else if(strncmp(c1, buffer, strlen(c1))==0 && ok ==0){
                    int lungCom, lungNume;
                    char name[lungNume];
                    lungCom=strlen(buffer); //lungimea comenzii
                    lungNume=lungCom-strlen(c1); //lungimea numelui
                    name[lungNume]='\0';
                    strncpy(name,&buffer[lungCom-lungNume],lungNume);//pun numele din comanda in variabia name
                    printf("\n[copil] asta e numele: %s ", name);
                    printf("\n[copil] %s", w1);
                    if(Search_in_File_name("nume.txt", name)==4){// daca am gasit numele in lista
                        i=i+1;
                        printf("----%d----",i);
                        send(newSocket, v1, strlen(v1), 0);
                        bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));      
                        ok=1;
                        printf("\n[copil] am trimis mesajul: %s \n", v1); 
                    }else{ // daca nu am gasit numele in lista
                        send(newSocket, v2, strlen(v2), 0);
                        printf("\n[copil] am trimis mesajul: %s \n", v2); 
                        bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));      
                    }
                    
                    
                }else if(strcmp(buffer, "logout")==0 && ok == 1){
                    printf("incercare delogare de la %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
                    printf("delogat de la  %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
                    ok=0;
                    printf("Client: %s\n", buffer);
                    send(newSocket, d1, strlen(d1), 0);
                    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                
                }else if(strcmp(buffer, "logout")==0 && ok == 0){
                    printf("incercare delogare de la %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
                    printf("Client: %s\n", buffer);
                    send(newSocket, d2, strlen(d2), 0);
                    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                    
                }else if(strcmp(buffer, "cos")==0 && ok == 1){
                    printf("incercare creare cos de la %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
                    printf("Client: %s\n", buffer);
                    printf("----%d---:", ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
                    //nume_fisier=creare_cos_client(nume_client);
                    //printf("---nume_fisier: %s", nume_fisier);
                    send(newSocket, cos1, strlen(cos1), 0);
                    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                    
                        
                }else{
                    printf("Client: %s\n", buffer);
                    send(newSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    close(newSocket);


    return 0;
}
```

If i delete that "int i=0; " before the fork my program works fine but as soon as i add it back(anywhere) the client can't take any input and the server doesn't check if the name is in the file or not. [image: this is how it freezes]

Comment: Shouldn't you get a compile error if you remove "int i = 0;"

Comment: Something like this usually means there's undefined behavior somewhere in the program. Adding the variable just causes the UB to behave differently.

Comment: With networking buffer overflows are quite common.

Comment: I get an error only if i use it somewhere else but because it doesn't work if i don't declare it i delete all its sightings

Comment: Stop focusing on that `int i`. It's a symptom not a cause. You have already been told that it is a clear indication of Undefined Behaviour. Look for bugs in other parts of your code. People have already pointed out multiple bugs in your code - look at those bugs and forget about the `int i`.

Answer (score 3):

```
            recv(newSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);
            if(strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0){
```

Two mistakes here:

1. You ignore the return value of `recv`. So you have no idea how many bytes you received. How can you do anything useful with some data if you have no idea how much data you have?
2. You can only pass a C-style string to `strcmp`. At this point, `buffer` only contains the raw data you received from the other side. It isn't a C-style string because, by definition, a C-style string has a terminating zero byte.

You have another more fundamental problem though -- your use of `strcmp` suggests you think you are using a message protocol and have received a message. But you are using TCP and TCP is not a message protocol.

It's hard to say precisely why adding `int i =0;` saves you from crashing or freezing. But my guess is that the zero just happens to be stored in memory after the buffer and so, by luck, provides the terminating zero byte that `strcmp` requires. But that's just a guess.

Comment: if I don't add "int i;" or "int i=0" the program stops working.

Comment: @BiaGH24990 Undefined behavior will cause your program to behave unpredictably. The behavior of `strcmp` if passed something other than a pointer to a string is undefined. So it's not surprising your program sometimes crashes or freezes and sometimes does't.